# Obtaining a Crash Dump from a dying IIS ASP.NET Worker Process

Tags: iis, debugging, worker-process

(Not sure if this is an IIS problem or not, so if this is better suited for SO I'll happily move it...)

We have an IIS-hosted application that is sporadically dying, and the event logs claim that the application pool is reporting itself as unhealthy due to deadlocks. I'm attempting to get a crash dump of the process as it's dying, to see if we can pinpoint the problem.

I have following this [Microsoft KB Article #828222](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/828222), which says there is an option on the application pool to enable "Orphaned Worker Process" analysis. We've followed those steps exactly -- installed the debugger tools, enabled the Orphaned Worker Process option for the application pool, and set up a batch file to run when it happens:

```
adsutil.vbs SET W3SVC/AppPools/MyAppPool/OrphanWorkerProcess TRUE
adsutil.vbs SET W3SVC/AppPools/MyAppPool/OrphanActionExe "c:\debug\dump.cmd"
adsutil.vbs SET W3SVC/AppPools/MyAppPool/OrphanActionParams "%1%"
```

The `debugdump.cmd` essentially just runs `cdb` on the PID of the dying process (after computing a unique file name):

```
c:\debug\cdb.exe -c ".dump /o /ma %FILENAME%;q" -p %1
```

The IIS side of the configuration *seems* to be correct -- it does try to run the batch file on the dying process. But it doesn't actually do anything, because according to `cdb`:

```
Cannot debug pid 3236, NTSTATUS 0xC000010A
    "An attempt was made to access an exiting process."
```

The whole point of this option, I assumed, was that IIS would *not* kill the process before the debugger had a chance to dump it; did I miss something in the configuration?

Comment: Having the same problem in 2022... Did you find a solution @KutuluMike ?